# Recover data of NAS damaged HDDs (SHR & Brtf format)

Tags: macos, terminal, hard-drive, nas

Do you know any program or tool in MacOSX or Ubuntu to grant acces and recover some data of both HHDs in Raid 1 in my Synology Disk Station. I've tried with Paragon exfat for Mac and I can see main folder structure but with no files inside. That units suffered some damage with a power failure and now I can't mount in my NAS and I would like to know if some data is posible to recover before reformat those disks again.

I've tried with mdadm in Ubuntu LiveCD as per Synology procedure
https://www.synology.com/es-es/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/Storage/How_can_I_recover_data_from_my_DiskStation_using_a_PC
but as you can see in attached image I really don't understand message because my knowledge of Ubuntu is null.

Thanks for your help and feedback.[image]

Comment: Please provide the output of `sudo file -s /dev/dm-0`.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of error messages, but rather transcribe them and use quote formatting. Screenshots and screen photos are hard to read, don't scale well, aren't indexed by search engines and aren't accessible for screen readers. You can [edit] your question to improve it.